error while running flutter app which works perfectly fine before
Im getting this error while running my flutter app which works fine few days back. Don't know what caused this issue. I'll provide the error response here
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/Users/user/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.3.7/android/build.gradle' line: 24

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':razorpay_flutter'.



No signature of method: build_84rk1aer9e4h35yup4e53do6i.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_84rk1aer9e4h35yup4e53do6i$_run_closure2) values: [build_84rk1aer9e4h35yup4e53do6i$_run_closure2@3cea241f]

Is there any solution to solve this ?

Verify that the android block of build.gradle is correctly defined and that there are no syntax errors.

@DroidFlutter The build.gradle files are ok. I just copied one from a working project only.

Try to downgrade version of razorpay_flutter package.

@DroidFlutter tried that too. This version of razorpay worked in this project. all of a sudden it stopped working with this error
